# UI Testing with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing the below code it shows me error `at ActivityTestRule` it displays *cannot find declaration to go*,does it not come inbuilt in Espresso

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: add please build.gradle file content

Answer (score 1):

It is part of Espresso but check whether you have added `Espresso` like shown below in build.gradle plus android test support library and sync the `gradle`.

```
androidTestCompile'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'  
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1')
```

Comment: i have added     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'   in the build.gradle

Comment: add other two libs for runner and rules in your build config  and import this -Import this -

import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

Comment: androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'  all added still the error persists

Comment: check if you are able to import this then your error will resolve import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the instrumentation runner?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To setup espresso please follow the following steps:-

**Step 1:** At first add the dependencies in your build.gradle file.

```
//Espresso Dependencies
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'`
```

**Step 2:** Go to Run -> Edit Configuration -> Click on the "+" symbol on the upper left and then click on `Android Test`. The in the General tab select your module which you want to test and then add this `"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` in the `Specific Instrumentation Runner` and the Click Ok.

**Step 3:** In your test case file add the following imports.

```
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
```